# Java Rest Template throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, spring-boot, illegalargumentexception, timsort

I am not using any **Comparators/Sorting** in my Java code, still it is throwing " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!" Exception.

Below is the piece of code that throws exception on the restTemplate.exchange line on debugging.

**Started getting this exception when I changed the version of spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.3.9 to 2.5.3**

How should I resolve this?

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
Function call : AzureCredentials oStoreCreds = azureAutoConfiguration.getObjectStoreCreds(mop, new RestTemplate());

    @Bean
    @Profile("cf-azure")
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public AzureCredentials getObjectStoreCreds(ManagedObjectStoreProperties mosp, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    try {
            String managed_instance_url = mosp.getGet_managed_instance_url().replace("{tenant_id}", tenantId);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setBasicAuth(mosp.getUser(), mosp.getPassword());
            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
            ResponseEntity<ManagedObjectStoreAzureClientResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(managed_instance_url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, ManagedObjectStoreAzureClientResponse.class);
            azureCredentials = response.getBody().getCredentials();
        } catch (RestClientException exception) {
            LoggerHelper.logError(LoggerHelper.getLogger(this.getClass()), "Fetching managed object store credentials failed.");
        }catch (Exception e){
            LoggerHelper.logError(LoggerHelper.getLogger(this.getClass()), "Generic Exception - Fetching managed object store credentials failed.");
        }
   return azureCredentials;
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!] with root cause
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1464) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.http.MediaType.sortBySpecificityAndQuality(MediaType.java:780) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:254) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.sap.icd.mt.config.FilterConfig$1.doFilter(FilterConfig.java:36) ~[mt-spring-boot-starter-2.11.2-20200305172704.jar:na]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_301]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
   2021-09-28T19:56:56.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [na:1.8.0_301]
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace along with a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Have provided the stack trace.

Comment: Please show the initialization of `restTemplate`. Best would be a minimal reproducible example as Sotirios already said.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't appear to have anything to do with restTemplate.exchange method. Are you sure that is where the problem is?

Comment: @yankee, have added the initialization of restTemplate. Dont think would be able to provide minimal reproducible example as it is just a part my code.

Comment: @madteapot I get this issue only when I deploy my project on cloud. Dont get this error locally, so on adding SysOut everywhere, restTemplate seems to be the point of failure.

Comment: It will be useful to put a break point on org.springframework.http.MediaType.sortBySpecificityAndQuality(MediaType.java:780) and log the value of `mediaTypes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace indicates that for some reason the Comparator method for the `MediaType.java` class is not ok. As you pointed out that this seems to work locally but not in the cloud I would suggest you compare runtimes.

Looking through the source code for the `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java` the sorting method is called when the content type for the response can not be found. Maybe you can force a content type by setting an `accept` header in the request. Assuming your expecting a JSON response:

`headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`

Not sure if this fixes it though, as I could not reproduce the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some problem for [the comparator QUALITY_VALUE_COMPARATOR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java#L788) inside `MediaType.sortBySpecificityAndQuality`, I am able to reproduce the exception with below program. [A ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27488) is raised in github.

Run in *Win 10* *openjdk version "16" 2021-03-16*

```java
public class TestMediaTypeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> mapSize1 = Map.of("a", "b");
        Map<String, String> mapSize2 = Map.of("a", "b", "c", "d");
        Map<String, String> mapSize3 = Map.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
        List<MediaType> mediaTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("c", "a", mapSize1));
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("c", "a", mapSize2));
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("c", "a", mapSize3));
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("b", "a", mapSize1));
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("b", "a", mapSize2));
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("b", "a", mapSize3));
            mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("b", "a", mapSize2));
        }
        MediaType.sortBySpecificityAndQuality(mediaTypeList);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This check](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java#L801) looks very suspicious: returning 0 if things aren't equal?